# How to append to beginning of java string using replace with regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I use java string replaceAll or replaceFirst to append to beginning?

```
String joe = "Joe";
String helloJoe = joe.replaceAll("\\^", "Hello");
```

> Desired Output:  "Hello Joe"

Comment: Why are you using regex for this?

Comment: You can't "append to the beginning of a string" anyway since strings in Java are immutable. You'll create a new string object anyway.

Comment: Okey dokey!   lambdaStuff.map(s->s.replace("^","Hello")).orElse(""));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to escape `^` because `^` is a special meta character in regex which matches the start of a line.

```
String helloJoe = whatever.replaceFirst("^", "Hello ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could perform a simple `String` append with `+`, or [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) like

```
String whatever = "Joe";
String helloJoe = String.format("Hello %s", whatever);
// String helloJoe = "Hello " + whatever;
System.out.println(helloJoe);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
Hello Joe
```